# How to transform a tuple to a string of values without comma and parentheses

Tags: python

I retrieved data from a sql query by using

```
bounds = cursor.fetchone()
```

And I get a tuple like:

```
(34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)
```

And I would like to have a string like `34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344`

Does a function exist that can do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> mystring = ' '.join(map(str, (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)))
>>> print mystring
34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344
```

You'll have to use map here (which converts all the items in the tuple to strings) because otherwise you will get a `TypeError`.

---

A bit of clarification on the [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function:

`map(str, (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)` is equivalent to `[str(i) for i in (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)]`.

It's a tiny bit faster than using a list comprehension:

```
$ python -m timeit "map(str, (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.93 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "[str(i) for i in (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.02 usec per loop
```

As shown in the comments to this answer, `str.join()` can take a generator instead of a list. Normally, this would be faster, but in this case, it is *slower*.

If I were to do:

```
' '.join(itertools.imap(str, (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)))
```

It would be slower than using `map()`. The difference is that `imap()` returns a generator, while `map()` returns a list (in python 3 it returns a generator)

If I were to do:

```
''.join(str(i) for i in (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344))
```

It would be slower than putting brackets around the *list* comprehension, because of reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/1240268).

---

In your (OP's) case, either option does not really matter, as performance doesn't seem like a huge deal here. But if you are ever dealing with large tuples of floats/integers, then now you know what to use for maximum efficiency :).

Comment: In Python 3, your answer is good because ``map()`` is a generator in Python 3. But in Python2, it would be better to use ``imap()``

Comment: @eyquem actually it's faster and more efficient to use a list comp rather than a generator for a join: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/1240268

Comment: @AndyHayden Wow, that's very interesting. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @AndyHayden Thank you very very much for your link. The information given by the Raymond Hettinger's answer and the discussion between Raymond and ovgolovin is very interesting. - I upvote two of your best answers seen in your user's page

Comment: I have the exact same speed using map or list comprehension, ie: 1.87 usec per loop

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Perhaps for such a small tuple, yes, but for much bigger tuples there will be bigger differences

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to produce any arbitrary formatting if you're willing to use `*` magic. To handle the specific case of this question, with a single separator, is actually a little cumbersome:

```
>>> bounds = (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)
>>> "{} {} {} {}".format(*bounds)

34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344
```

A more robust version that handles any length, like `join`, is:

```
>>> len(bounds)*"{} ".format(*bounds)
```

But the value added is that if you want to extend your formatting to something more involved you've got the option:

```
>>> "{} --> | {:>10} | {:>10} | {:>10} |".format(*bounds)

34.2424 --> |   -64.2344 |    76.3534 |    45.2344 |
```

From here, your string [formatting options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) are very diverse.

Comment: You solution is faster than using map or list comprehension, ie: 1.72 usec per loop instead of 1.87

Answer (score 5):

If I've got your message, you are getting tuple of floats, am I right?

If so, the following code should work:

```
In [1]: t = (34.2424 , -64.2344 , 76.3534 , 45.2344)

In [2]: ' '.join([str(x) for x in t])
Out[2]: '34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344'
```

We're converting every value in tuple to string here, because [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join) method can work only with lists of string. 
If `t` is a tuple of strings the code will be just `' '.join(t)`.

In case you're getting string in format `"(34.2424 , -64.2344 , 76.3534 , 45.2344)"`, you should firstly get rid of unnescessary parthensis and commas:

```
In [3]: t = "(34.2424 , -64.2344 , 76.3534 , 45.2344)"

In [4]: t.strip('()')
Out[4]: '34.2424 , -64.2344 , 76.3534 , 45.2344'

In [5]: numbers = t.strip('()')

In [6]: numbers.split(' , ')
Out[6]: ['34.2424', '-64.2344', '76.3534', '45.2344']

In [7]: ' '.join(numbers.split(' , '))
Out[7]: '34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
>>> a = (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)
>>> ' '.join(str(i) for i in a)
'34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344
```

Comment: Writing ``[str(i) for i in a]``, it means that a list object is first created before ``' '.join()`` has to work. But it's possible to write ``' '.join(str(i) for i in a)`` : in this case, ``join()`` gets every ``str(i)`` as they are furnished one after the other by the generator ``str(i) for i in a)``. See also my comment to Haidro's answer.

Comment: Actually list comprehension is better with join: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/1240268

Comment: Thanks Andy, thanks for noting that, I've read this question about 2 days ago, but I've already fotgot that I have some answers on this topic. i'm learning python with SO :)

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:#iterate over entire rows
    print('row : 'row)#prints the entire row
    for d in row:#prints each item of the row
        print(d)
```

### Output:

```
row :  (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)
34.2424
-64.2344
76.3534
45.2344
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use the following code:

```
i = 0
for row in data:
       print(row[i])
       i++
```