# How to remove ) ' and , in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the code.

```
Password = "Here is your password: ", UpperCase,RandomNum
print(Password)
```

The result is something like this.

```
('Here is your password: ', 'Ajar', 98)
```

I have tried this.

```
print(Password).replace(",","")
```

But i get this error messege.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Krun2810/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 59, in <module>
    print(Password.replace(",",""))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

How do I remove `,`, `)` and ` from the result?

Comment: Python 2.7 [reached EOL at the start of 2020](https://endoflife.date/python). Strongly consider upgrading to Python 3.

Comment: the result = ('Here is your password: ', 'Ajar', 98) which is not a string but as the error suggests is a tuple. You cannot do a replace on a tuple but only on a string. First you would need join all elements of your tuple into a string and then you could do the replace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform a tuple to a string of values without comma and parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17426386/2745495)

Comment: `Password = UpperCase + str(RandomNum); print "Here is your password:", Password`

Comment: How this question was upvoted 3 points is beyond my understanding !

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
Password = "Here is your password: " + str(UpperCase) + str(RandomNum)
```

Comment: I think the OP would be helped more if you would explain WHY he should do that

Answer (score 1):

```
Password = "Here is your password: ", UpperCase,RandomNum
```

On this line you're actually making a tuple instead of making a string! Instead of a ',' character try a + character.

Consider replacing this line:

```
Password = "Here is your password: ", UpperCase,RandomNum
```

with this line:

```
Password = "Here is your password: " + UpperCase + str(RandomNum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do something like this.

```
UpperCase, RandomNum = "Ajay", 98

Password = "Here is your password: %s %s" %(UpperCase,RandomNum)
print(Password)
```

**output**

```
'Here is your password: Ajay 98'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) with 3 elements. When you print it, it will display the string representation of that particular tuple. As the other answers suggest, one solution would be to concatenate the desired strings into one string variable, and print it.

```
pwd = "Here is your password: " + str(UpperCase) + str(RandomNum)
print(pwd)
```

where `UpperCase` and `RandomNum` are your variables.